# Business Data Connectivity Metadata Store is currently unavailable in Sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, external-content-type

I use SharePoint 2013.

When I use SharePoint Designer and open my SharePoint website and select `External Content Types` I get this error :

```
Business Data Connectivity Metadata Store is 
currently unavailable in SharePoint designer 2013
```

How I can fix it ?

This question was ask in [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056229/business-data-connectivity-metadata-store-is-currently-unavailable-in-sharepoint) link but have not answer!?